# How do I calculate the uncertainty of a fraction raised to a power?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis, statistics

What is the uncertainty of:

$y=(\frac{a}{b})^{n}$

Would it be:

$\Delta y = n (\frac{\Delta a}{a}+\frac{\Delta b}{b}) y $

Comment: That looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncertainty through multiplication and division is additive, so if
$$
y=\frac{a}{b}
$$
then
$$
\Delta y = \Delta a + \Delta b
$$
in your case, since
$$
y= \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^n
$$
we have that
$$
\Delta y = n(\Delta a + \Delta b)
$$

Comment: I think yours is equivalent to this btw just with a quantity rather than a percentage, just writing it out incase others visit!